# Removing Second Last Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

i am working on code-first , and i need to remove second last migration i.e. basically need to remove non last Migration by migration name.

I used 
    Remove-Migration 
but it only removes last added migration.

i tried deleting from solution but there are few code left in DBContextModelSnapshot.cs.

is their any cleaner way to remove earlier added migration in EF Core.

Thanks

Comment: Try Apply-Migration SecondToLastMigrationName before removing.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting history is dangerous, but if you know what you're doing, here is the best way to do it.

```
Update-Database SecondToLast
Remove-Migration
Remove-Migration
Add-Migration Last
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First update your database to the desired migration. In your case migrate to third last migration. Provide the name of the migration in target argument
   update-database -target:"third last migration"
2. Then remove your code changes for second last migration and delete the second last migration. Then run update-databse.

I would actually prefer to delete both last and second last migrations, then run add-migration and check the changes being made in the migration class and then run update-database.